# How do I get debug from "imap_open" function?

Tags: php, imap

I use "imap_open" function to connect to a IMAP server. In documentation there is information about /debug option in this function which "record protocol telemetry in application's debug log". I turned on this option but I can't find any logs anywhere. Where should I expect them?

Some guy wrote in comments in the documentation (http://php.net/manual/en/function.imap-open.php) that: "Do not bother using "/debug" flag in $mailbox or OP_DEBUG in $options. They do not do anything.". Is it really true?

Comment: The comment seems pretty clear: the debug flag causes the underlying C library to call the logging handler, but the PHP connection does not have a useful handler.

Comment: @Max. Thank you for your help.